# Is there a way to make two sibling components have asynchronous knowledge of a state in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, state, logoff

I have two components: **NavBar**, and **SignUp**.

In my **SignUp** component, I keep track of whether a user is currently logged in or not *via a state variable.*

Depending on the above state variable from **SignUp**, my **NavBar** component should change *(ex. the "sign in" icon should change to "sign out").*

***Two Questions:***

**1.** How can my NavBar have knowledge of the state of SignUp?

**2.** How can they both be in sync, changing dynamically, depending on the state of SignUp?

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Passing a prop to `Navbar` from `SignUp`'s JSX (ie: `<NavBar myProp={123}/>`), as you would add an attribute, will cause `NavBar` to automatically update when it changes.

Check out [React's official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) for more info on passing props.

Comment: Yes, but that is a parent-child relationship. i.e. that is implying that SignUp will render NavBar.

Comment: I have NavBar and SignUp both being rendered with a router/switch config on App.js, hence they are sibling components

Comment: Then you can either use [global hooks](https://github.com/CharlesStover/reactn), [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) or a parent element which passes to both `SignUp` and `Navbar` both the prop & a callback which modifies the same prop.